# Extract key and value from a List of a List of objects using LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq

Suppose I have this data.  As the contents of the rows source can be any type, I chose lists of objects to collect the data for processing, and there are nulls in the data.

```
List<object> row1 = new List<object>() {"id", 2345, null, "id", null, null};
List<object> row2 = new List<object>() { "name", "Joe", null, "Joe", null, null };
List<object> row3 = new List<object>() { "card no", 2222, null, "card no",null, null };


List<List<object>> rowCollection = new List<List<object>>();
rowCollection.Add(row1);
rowCollection.Add(row2);
rowCollection.Add(row3);
```

So I'm ending up with a `List<List<object>>` collection

I have a LINQ question please.

1. I know I can access individual data pieces with index's like this

   ```
   var result = rowCollection[0][0].ToString()
   ```
2. How can I use LINQ to extract the object values that are the next object after the key I'm searching for? For example, I want to search the list `rowCollection` and get the number 2345 by searching for the `id` key in the above collection of data. And there are possible duplicate keys in the row of data with a duplicate `id` key. But I only want the result for the first key in the rows searched for.

And the same for the others. Searching the `rowCollection`, I want to search for "name" and extract the value `"Joe" and search for "card no" and extract the number 2222.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Your data structure has no logic to it. There's no relationship between `"id"` and `2345`.

Comment: The relationship is that 2345 is the next object after "id". Same for the others.

Comment: This is a very obscure and confusing way to model data. What is the source of this data? Can this structure be changed?

Comment: I suggest using a different data structure. Use a `Dictionary<object, object>` or something like that.

Comment: The source  are rows extracted out of a 3rd party xls spreadsheet. i have no control of the data or how its structured in the source. it gets extracted in this way as rows of data like shown.

Comment: You don't need to keep the data in list format just because it came from a spreadsheet. You can create a class to store each row and then use LINQ on the list of class instances to get the data you need. This would make the code much easier to read!

Comment: I think you have a typo in row2, it looks like the 4th entry should be "name" and "Joe" should be the 5th entry.

Comment: Do you only want one result, or one result per row? Also, are the keys and values always in pairs? And, are the keys always `string`?

Comment: I dont think the rows matter , thinking about it. I guess all the rows could be flattened into one row. The important part is getting the value in the field after the first instance of the key im searching for.

Comment: @netmage i only need one result in searching for one key regardless of how many rows exist. so search for "id" return the value after it of 2345. One result for one search  The keys are always string and the keys and values are always in pairs. Key followed by value. value can be any type eg string or float or int etc etc.

Comment: Please see my edited questions. Also, is it possible for a key to be the last value in a row?

Comment: @netmage  a key will not be the last value in a row.

Comment: Use a dictionary :             Dictionary<string, List<object>> dict = rowCollection.GroupBy(x => x.Take(1).ToString(), y => (object)y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

Answer (score 0):

Using the extension method

```
public static object FirstValueForKey(this List<List<object>> src, string key) =>
    src.Select(row => { var idx = row.FindIndex(v => v?.ToString() == key); return idx >= 0 ? row[idx + 1] : null; }).FirstOrDefault(v => v != null);
```

You can find any key:

```
var idvalue = rowCollection.FirstValueForKey("id");
var namevalue = rowCollection.FirstValueForKey("name");
var cardnovalue = rowCollection.FirstValueForKey("card no");
```